# Creating audio fingerprint database

Tags: releasing-data, music, legal, audio

My company has created unique audio fingerprinting system that we use to detect music and advertisements on radio and TV (among other uses).  So far, we are used to dodging all requests for database creation since we are not sure where we are allowed to use music to create fingerprints or not.

So we leave our system opened and transfer that issue to end users, who upload their music and get reports for it.

What is proper take on this?  Just few notes:

- we have tools to extract fingerprints from on-line radio streams and other recorded materials, and we don't have to use original sources
- we would be happy to pay for ONE use of audio of the song
- we can not use any other existing fingerprint database, since our is proprietary.  Hm, how do others solve that issue?

Any concrete information on that?

Comment: I once attended a talk about a music database (they actually had copies of the music), and they said that their main concern was that whatever reports were generated couldn't be used to re-create the music they held ... that way, they could maintain their status as a dark archive.  I would suspect that if you don't keep a copy of the music, and only characteristics of the music (ie, the fingerprint), it'd be legal (assuming you had legal access to the music), but I'm not a lawyer, and you really should get someone to back you up if you're basing your business model on this.

Comment: Thx @Joe, I'm trying not to, at least not for now, until I actually find some answers and get some legal assistance.  I was hoping to get some info on actual cases that are in effect on the subject.

Comment: Have you considered a desktop client that scans the audio file and submit the results to your site?